# How to show touch point in front of bar Xamarin ColorPicker

Tags: xamarin

I'm trying to make a color picker bar and customizing I have encountered this problem (I'm learning with Xamarin). The problem is that I don't see how to make a touch pointer in front of the bar.
Any idea? How to do it?

Original repo https://github.com/UdaraAlwis/XFColorPickerControl

[Color picker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RrrzR.png)

```
// Painting the Touch point
using (SKPaint paintTouchPoint = new SKPaint())
{
paintTouchPoint.Style = SKPaintStyle.Fill;
paintTouchPoint.Color = SKColors.Black;
paintTouchPoint.IsAntialias = true;

var valueToCalcAgainst = (skCanvasWidth > skCanvasHeight) ? skCanvasWidth : skCanvasHeight;

var pointerCircleDiameterUnits = PointerCircleDiameterUnits+0.05; // 0.6 (Default)
pointerCircleDiameterUnits = (float)pointerCircleDiameterUnits / 10f; //  calculate 1/10th of that value
var pointerCircleDiameter = (float)(valueToCalcAgainst * pointerCircleDiameterUnits);

// Outer circle of the Pointer (Ring)
skCanvas.DrawCircle(
    _lastTouchPoint.X,
    _lastTouchPoint.Y,
    pointerCircleDiameter / 2, paintTouchPoint);

paintTouchPoint.Style = SKPaintStyle.Fill;
paintTouchPoint.Color = SKColors.White;
paintTouchPoint.IsAntialias = true;

valueToCalcAgainst = (skCanvasWidth > skCanvasHeight) ? skCanvasWidth : skCanvasHeight;

pointerCircleDiameterUnits = PointerCircleDiameterUnits; // 0.6 (Default)
pointerCircleDiameterUnits = (float)pointerCircleDiameterUnits / 10f; //  calculate 1/10th of that value
pointerCircleDiameter = (float)(valueToCalcAgainst * pointerCircleDiameterUnits);

// Outer circle of the Pointer (Ring)
skCanvas.DrawCircle(
    _lastTouchPoint.X,
    _lastTouchPoint.Y,
    pointerCircleDiameter / 2, paintTouchPoint);

// Draw another circle with picked color
paintTouchPoint.Color = touchPointColor;

var pointerCircleBorderWidthUnits = PointerCircleBorderUnits; // 0.3 (Default)
var pointerCircleBorderWidth = (float)pointerCircleDiameter *
                                        (float)pointerCircleBorderWidthUnits; // Calculate against Pointer Circle
                
// Inner circle of the Pointer (Ring)
skCanvas.DrawCircle(
    _lastTouchPoint.X,
    _lastTouchPoint.Y,
    ((pointerCircleDiameter - pointerCircleBorderWidth) / 2), paintTouchPoint);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I check the library part of your post, the xaml shows how to use the control to display the color picker like:

```
   <Frame
                x:Name="ColorPickerHolderFrame"
                CornerRadius="8"
                HeightRequest="200"
                HorizontalOptions="Center"
                WidthRequest="350">
                <controls:ColorPicker
                    x:Name="ColorPicker"
                    ColorListDirection="Horizontal"
                    GradientColorStyle="DarkToColorsToLightStyle"
                    PickedColorChanged="ColorPicker_PickedColorChanged"
                    PointerCircleBorderUnits="0.3"
                    PointerCircleDiameterUnits="0.7">
                    <controls:ColorPicker.ColorList>
                        <x:Array Type="{x:Type x:String}">
                            <!--  Red  -->
                            <x:String>#ff0000</x:String>
                            <!--  Yellow  -->
                            <x:String>#ffff00</x:String>
                            <!--  Green (Lime)  -->
                            <x:String>#00ff00</x:String>
                            <!--  Aqua  -->
                            <x:String>#00ffff</x:String>
                            <!--  Blue  -->
                            <x:String>#0000ff</x:String>
                            <!--  Fuchsia  -->
                            <x:String>#ff00ff</x:String>
                            <!--  Red  -->
                            <x:String>#ff0000</x:String>
                        </x:Array>
                    </controls:ColorPicker.ColorList>
                </controls:ColorPicker>
            </Frame>
```